p5.touchgui buttons not displaying correctly
I'm making a flappy bird game using p5.play and p5.js with the gui using p5.touchgui. All was fine for a while until one day my gui stopped working properly. At first I thought maybe the library was updated and that caused some issue, but this isn't the case. I have 4 buttons

startButton = createButton("Start", 20, 20, 100, 40);
pauseButton = createButton("Pause", 20, 60, 100, 40);
resetButton = createButton("Reset", 20, 100, 100, 40);
speedUpButton = createToggle("2x Speed", 20, 160, 100, 40);

pauseButton.visible = false;
resetButton.visible = false;


the start button is meant to be visible only at the beginning and disappear after being clicked
the pause button isnt visible to start with - turns visible when the game is being played and will pause the game when pressed. the pause button will then disappear one the player hits a pipe
the reset button is not visible the whole time up until the player hits a pipe at which point will reset the game if pressed
the speed up button is displayed only at the beginning of the game - when toggled to true the game will run at 2x speed essentially and when false the game will run at a 'normal' speed. the button isnt visible when the game is being player


like i said one day this was all working fine and the next it just stopped.

currently on the startig menu the issue is that he text on my start button doesnt appear and hovering over over the 2x speed button makes the start button also change color

while playing the outline of the start button and 2x speed button are both visible when they shouldnt be

similar issue once the player has touched the pipe/wall

after going to low and resetting the pause button outline is now visible too
I've checked that the i have the latet version of the libraries are being used and that the buttons are being set the invisible when they are meant to not be seen/displayed
